# Generic Type From Enum & The Builder Pattern

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I'm trying to create a builder pattern that uses generics to provide type checking on some of the methods.  Currently I have the following working:

```
ParameterBuilder.start(String.class).setName("foo").setDefaultValue("Hello").build();
ParameterBuilder.start(Integer.class).setName(bar).setDefaultValue(42).build();
ParameterBuilder.start(Boolean.class).setName(bar).setDefaultValue(false).build();
```

Using the code:

```
public class ParameterBuilder<T> {
  private String name;
  private T defaultValue;

  public static <T2> ParameterBuilder<T2> start(Class<T2> type) {
    return new ParameterBuilder<T2>();
  }
  // Other methods excluded for example
}
```

So the type of the input for the `setDefaultValue` method is defined by what's passed into the `start` method, just as I want.

But now I want to extend what's being passed into `start()` to contain a little more information. Essentially I want to pass in a "type" for the parameters I creating.  Sometimes these parameters will be things like "email", "url" etc.  The default value will still be of a known type (String in those cases), so I'd like to have something like:

```
ParameterBuilder.start(EMAIL).setName("email").setDefaultValue("foo@bar.com").build();
ParameterBuilder.start(URL).setName("website").setDefaultValue("http://www.somewhere.com").build();
```

Where at the moment EMAIL & URL are enums, containing amongst other things - the class of the default value.  But if I go down this route, how would I instantiate the parameter builder?

```
public static <T2> ParameterBuilder<T2> start(ParameterType paramType) {
  Class<T2> type = paramType.getTypeClass();
  // How do I instantiate my ParameterBuilder with the right type?
}
```

If it can't be done using enums (which I can see being the case), does anyone have a suggestion for a different solution?

Comment: Can you show what exactly is `EMAIL`, `URL`. Are they 2 different enums? Are they instances of two enums? What are they?

Comment: In my case, I had a ParameterType echoing something like: `public enum ParameterType { STRING(String.class, "String"), INTEGER(Integer.class, "Integer"), MULTILINE(String.class, "Multine Text"), HTML(String.class, "HTML"), DATE(Date.class, "Date"), BOOLEAN(Boolean.class, "Boolean"); // Methods followed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need one enum per class type (I don't see how you could have one enum cover several types and keep the thing working). In that case, a common generic interface could do what you want. You can then create some sort of factory to provide the enum constants if that helps.

This compiles:

```
static interface ParameterType<T> {}

static enum ParameterTypeEnum implements ParameterType<String> { EMAIL; }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ParameterBuilder
           .start(ParameterTypeEnum.EMAIL)
           .setName("email")
           .setDefaultValue("foo@bar.com")
           .build();
}

public static class ParameterBuilder<T> {

    private String name;
    private T defaultValue;

    public static <T2> ParameterBuilder<T2> start(ParameterType<T2> paramType) {
        return new ParameterBuilder<T2>();
    }

    ParameterBuilder<T> setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    ParameterBuilder<T> setDefaultValue(T defaultValue) {
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
        return this;
    }

    void build() {}
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a sensible way of doing it.  This way I could have StringParameterEnum, IntegerParameterEnum etc. which will still leave the code quite clean. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the context in what you want to use this, but I think the following might be an option.

You can follow the Open/Closed principle and create an interface `Parameter` and have one implementation per type. The benefit of this, is that you don't need to add a new enum value for each new Parameter you want. You can later pass the class to `ParameterBuilder` rather than the enum and the `ParameterBuilder` and `Parameter` would work together to build what you need.

So `ParameterBuilder.start()` could return an instance of the specific `Parameter` and the parameter might have different methods depending on the type of parameter.

I don't think this answer is really good, but hopefully can give you a hint in how to build a potential solution for your context.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object hierachie for these Email and Url types

```
public class DefaultType {
    protected String name;
    protected String defaultValue;
    //some constructor
}

public class EmailType extends DefaultType {
    ...
}

public class URLType extends DefaultType {
    ...
}
```

then the parameter builder could look something like this:

```
public static ParameterBuilder start(DefaultType type) {
    ParameterBuilder builder = new ParameterBuilder(type);
    builder.setType(type);
    return builder;
}
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
ParameterBuilder.start(new EmailType("name","value");...
```

does this help or dont you want to go in this direction?